# Is $e^z$ bounded on the complex plane? if so why?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was workin on some questions and I got really confused, my question is: Is $e^z$ bounded on the complex plane? if so why?

I know $e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta)$ but I don't know if these are bounded in the complex plane.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not even bounded on the real axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not bounded. Bounded entire functions should be constant by Liouville's Theorem and $e^z$ is an entire function that is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

Is it bounded on the real line?  Is the real line part of the complex plane?  The answers to these will imply the answer to your question.  No need for the $e^{i\theta}$ formula.